ESP32 no longer setting timezone correctly from NTP
Having a weird problem.  My ESP32 code should get the time from an NTP server, use setenv() to change timezone to PST, then print out the time every 10 sec.
The weird thing is that my code was working correctly a couple days ago.  Then it stopped printing out the correct time for my timezone & now prints out the basic epoch 1969 time instead.  To be exact, it gives me Dec 1969 (because 0:00 Jan 1, 1970 - 8 hours for PST = 16:00 Dec 31,1969).  I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything, and I even reverted to older code that for sure used to give the correct timezone, but even there it now gives me the 1969 time.
I verified that the TZ env variable is being correctly set to "PST8PDT", and the timezone change is definitely being applied since it's giving me Dec 1969 instead of Jan 1970.  So I think the problem is when I get the time from the NTP?  Unsure if the NTP server stopped serving me for whatever reason?  Or maybe I just committed a stupid mistake.  Any insight would be appreciated.
Edit:  Also ran the code with a esp_netif_sntp_sync_wait() for 15 minutes, which failed, so seems that it never connects to the NTP server at all...
Here's a snippet of the relevant code (without the esp_netif_sntp_sync_wait() blocking it):
void wifi_init_sta(void) {
    s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

    // use NETIF lib for application layer abstraction & thread safety
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());

    // choose server & start service
    char ntp_server_address[] = "pool.ntp.org";
    esp_sntp_config_t sntp_configs = ESP_NETIF_SNTP_DEFAULT_CONFIG(ntp_server_address);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_sntp_init(&sntp_configs));
    ESP_LOGI(NTP, "Service started from %s", ntp_server_address);

    // set PST timezone
    char timezone[] = "PST8PDT";
    setenv("TZ", timezone, 1);     // change timezone env variable
    tzset();    // set runtime timezone to TZ env variable (auto checks daylight savings)
    ESP_LOGI(NTP, "Timezone set to %s", timezone);


    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

    // init wifi
    wifi_init_config_t wifi_configs = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&wifi_configs));

    // handler events
    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;

    // handler check if got wifi ID data
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                        ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                        &wifi_connection_events_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_any_id));
    // handler check if got IP data
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT,
                                                        IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,
                                                        &wifi_connection_events_handler,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        &instance_got_ip));

    wifi_config_t sta_configs = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
            .threshold.authmode = ESP_WIFI_SCAN_AUTH_MODE_THRESHOLD,
            .sae_pwe_h2e = ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE,
            .sae_h2e_identifier = EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER,
        },
    };

    // set sta mode, configs, & start wifi
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &sta_configs));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

    // Block until one of these events occurs
    EventBits_t wifiEventBits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
            WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
            pdFALSE,
            pdFALSE,
            portMAX_DELAY);

    // react to the event that occurred
    if (wifiEventBits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(STA, "Successfully connected to AP SSID: %s", EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID);
    } else if (wifiEventBits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(STA, "Failed to connect to SSID: %s", EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID);
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(STA, "Unexpected error occured when attempting to connect to SSDI: %s", EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID);
    }

    ESP_LOGI(STA, "wifi_init_sta() finished.");
}


// Task to periodically print time.
void vPrintTimeTask(void* periodSec) {
    TickType_t* xPeriodMS = (TickType_t*) periodSec;
    *xPeriodMS *= 1000;     // convert from sec to ms

    time_t secondsSinceEpoch;
    struct tm* localTime;
    TickType_t xPrevWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    BaseType_t xDelayUntilSuccess;

    while(1) {
        secondsSinceEpoch = time(NULL);   // get current system time
        localTime = localtime(&secondsSinceEpoch);
        ESP_LOGI(NTP, "Current time is:  %s", asctime(localTime));
        xDelayUntilSuccess = xTaskDelayUntil(&xPrevWakeTime,  pdMS_TO_TICKS(*xPeriodMS));
    }
}


void app_main(void) 
{
    // init NVS partition
    esp_err_t nvs_return_handle = nvs_flash_init();
    if (nvs_return_handle == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || nvs_return_handle == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
      ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
      nvs_return_handle = nvs_flash_init();
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_return_handle);

    ESP_LOGI(STA, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    wifi_init_sta();

    // Print Time Task
    TickType_t* periodSecParam = malloc(sizeof(TickType_t));
    *periodSecParam = 10;
    BaseType_t taskCreateStatus = xTaskCreate(vPrintTimeTask, "Print time", 1024 * 4,
                                              (void*) periodSecParam, 1, NULL);
    if(taskCreateStatus == pdPASS) {
        ESP_LOGI(GPIO, "vPrintTimeTask() task creation successful");
    }
}


"so seems that it never connects to the NTP server at all...", on wifi_init_sta(void) code, how could you connect to a ntp server even before the wifi connection is established?

@hcheung WOW.  Seems I need to stop coding in the afternoons after 9+ hr work days.   Thanks for the extra set of eyes
